How to configure nginx on AWS EB properly to rewrite the URLs
I have a Flask app hosted on AWS EB. I also have another app for documentation hosted on Vercel.
I want my flask application would somehow rewrite the URL, so instead of
mywebsite.com/docs/getting-started

it would actually load the content from
vercel-docs.com/docs/getting-started

To achieve it, I created a file called "custom.config" and put it in the following path under my Flask local folder:
.platform/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf

Here is the content of this file:
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location /docs/ {
        proxy_pass https://vercel-docs.app/docs/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    }
}

But I can't make it work.
I have the following error shown on the log:
2024/09/02 23:18:13.732702 [INFO] Running command: /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2024/09/02 23:18:13.832205 [INFO] nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

If I rename the custom.config to the proxy.config I have another error:
"location" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:3

How to make it work?
